# Mock an entire rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really wasn't sure how to title this question but here we go.

Basically, I develop on Ubuntu and my server is Ubuntu, so whenever I need to install redis or imagemagick or whatever it's not a problem as I know it will work on the server just fine if I can install it locally. `sudo apt-get` is brilliant.

Now, I have a designer who just works in html + css + js, but is happy to work directly on the rails project (as a git repo) if I just point out where all the files are. This will definitely be for the best as right now he drop-boxes me all the html and I need to spend 20mins + copy pasting it all into the repository.

However, he runs OSX mavericks, and doesn't want to install an Ubuntu VM. I didn't think it would be a big deal because OSX is unix, but it's really different and really irritating.

Installing postgres, redis, image-magick is a huge chore, and now, whenever I need to install an application, I dread it because it's not 'will it work on my PC + the server' but 'will it work on my PC + the server + and OSX bl**dy Mavericks'. Every time I install something it's a faff.

So I'm wondering if I can mock out a rails project? All he needs to edit are the views, html and css. Is there a a gem or something that can mock out the database, redis, image magick etc...

Something where I can set up fake example data to populate the instance variables would be a good start.

Comment: You could also consider using a cloud IDE..

Comment: Try mirage gem, Actually i tried it when i need to get data from other API.  In test i use dummy responses rather than original

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely many approaches to that. One that I have found to work is to have a separate staging environment where designers are allowed to push their changes. Upon new commits being pushed, the staging environment is redeployed automatically.

The designers can see almost instantly how their changes reflect on the actual product and under production-like settings.